# Different tokens for users of same gcm application with constant Sender_ID

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

how does token for gcm works? are they remain same for all users because the sender id is constant or they can be changed for different user?

Comment: I believe that what happened here is that the device is registered for multiple tokens maybe due to uninstalling the app. You can refer to this documentation about [canonical IDs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration#canonical-ids) and how it works. "If a bug in the client app triggers multiple registrations for the same device, it can be hard to reconcile state and the client app might end up with duplicate messages." is what is written in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks! i'll try that.